# Dolphin File Manager Search Issues

Tags: files, kde, 17.04, dolphin

I am currently using the KDE Plasma Desktop Environment with it's Dolphin File Manager but when I am searching for files, most of the times it would either return no results or cause the program and even the desktop to freeze.

Anyone had the same experience and/or have any ideas on resolving this issue?

Comment: Do the other searches work? The ones for images, audio files, videos?

Comment: No, they do not.

Comment: If you don't get a solution here, sign up and ask at https://www.kubuntuforums.net. All the searches work for me but I'm on Kubuntu 16.04 so I don't know what to suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching for and deleting all files and folders containing the keyword `baloo` in the user directory `/home/username/` solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

deleting the baloo files didn't help in my case. It was deleting
home/username/.config/session/dolphin_dolphin_dolphin
that did the trick.